# Screen keeps clicking on profile button when I click elsewhere

Tags: android, kotlin, android-button

Whenever I click anywhere on the screen, it seems that the profile button which is on the left keeps on getting clicked. Even if i click another button it gets clicked

```
@Composable
fun TopAppBar() {
    Surface() {
        Column {
            Row(
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp)
            ) {
                IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Filled.AccountCircle, contentDescription = "Profile"
                    )
                }
                Text(
                    text = "Overview",
                    color = Color.Black,
                    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
                )
                IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Filled.Notifications,
                        contentDescription = "Notifications"
                    )
                }
                IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Filled.Menu, contentDescription = "Menu"
                    )
                }
            }
            Divider(color = Color.Black, thickness = 1.dp)
            

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, there is also a built-in composable `TopAppBar` that seems to do something very similar to what your version does. Is there is reason you don't use the built-in version?

Comment: to me, the composable function you provided looks good. The problem might be on other side of the codebase

Comment: @Leviathan Sorry Im a beginner and this is my first real project that Im working on so im trying to figure out things. So instead of creating a function I should just use the TopAppBar composable inside the class?

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/components/app-bars to learn more about app bars in android